# Element range index with local name "c" gives XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I created an Element range index on S, P, C, O (RDF) but C is not working even after reindexing and throwing an error.

```
XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND - No element range index for fn:QName("", "c") http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show code how you are using the index? And did reindex finish?

Comment: Is reindexing enabled on that database, and have you allowed enough time for indexing to complete for these new indexes? When enabled, you can see from the database status whether it is in the process of reindexing. You won't "see" that new index until all docs that need reindexing have been processed.

Comment: I manually reindex everything and after sometime it did work. Thanks